# why can't I open facebook and twitter app with ios 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, twitter, ios9

Before ios9 comes, I used following code to open facebook app with my app when button clicked.using this if the phone has facebook app, it opens the facebook app and, if it is not, it opens the safari browser.same for the twitter.this is my code.

```
- (IBAction)facebookButton:(id)sender {
    NSURL *facebookUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/number"];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:facebookUrl]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:facebookUrl];
    }
    else{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com/number"]];
    }

}

- (IBAction)twitterButton:(id)sender {
    NSURL *twitterUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"twitter://profile/"];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:twitterUrl]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:twitterUrl];
    }
    else{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.twitter.com/"]];
    }
}
```

this worked fine, before iOS 9.but now if app exists or not, it only opens with safari.help me with this

Comment: If you read the log messages that iOS prints out when you try, you will find out why it doesn't work.

Comment: yes, thanx and I got the answer

Comment: also go through this post http://awkwardhare.com/post/121196006730/quick-take-on-ios-9-url-scheme-changes

Comment: again, thanx both of you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

we have to add followings in `info.plist`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From Apple documentation on `canOpenURL:` method:

> If your app is linked on or after iOS 9.0, you must declare the URL
>   schemes you want to pass to this method. Do this by using the
>   LSApplicationQueriesSchemes array in your Xcode project’s Info.plist
>   file. For each URL scheme you want your app to use with this method,
>   add it as a string in this array.
>
> If your (iOS 9.0 or later) app calls this method using a scheme you
>   have not declared, the method returns NO, whether or not an
>   appropriate app for the scheme is installed on the device.
>
> Unlike this method, the openURL: method is not constrained by the
>   LSApplicationQueriesSchemes requirement: If an app that handles a
>   scheme is installed on the device, the openURL: method works, whether
>   or not you have declared the scheme.

Apple add this change to API, because `canOpenURL:` method was often used to receive information about applications, installed on user device, without actual `openURL:` calls.

Issue can be resolved in the following ways:

- Add "fb" and "twitter" URL schemes into LSApplicationQueriesSchemes array in your Info.plist;
- `openURL:` method returns NO if URL wasn't successfully opened. You can rewrite code in following way to avoid `canOpenURL:` call:

  ```
  if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/number"]]) {
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com/number"]];
  }
  ```
- Look into Universal Links, that works in similar way - open application, if it is available on device, otherwise URL is opened in Safari.

Comment: I figured it out bro, thanx for your nice explanation.I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Custom deep linking schemas does not work on iOS9 anymore. You need to use Universal Links. See [this](https://www.appsflyer.com/blog/how-to-set-up-ios-9-universal-links-for-your-app/) guide.